# iOS7 App crash issue which works fine in iOS7.1 and above

Tags: ios7

```
Symbol not found: _OSAtomicDecrement32 app crash issue in iOS7
which works fine in version higher than iOS7.1 and above.

 <Notice>: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OSAtomicDecrement32
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/.....
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Jan 29 12:07:01 admines-iPhone LoxaBeauty[3536] <Notice>: dyld: Symbol not found: _OSAtomicDecrement32
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/.....
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

This is the output when I run the app on iOS7 device crashes but works fine with iOS7.1 and above

Comment: Can paste some code.? So we can understand where and why it crash?

Comment: Hi Shreyansh Shah, I've added the device log output for app crash in iOS7.0 if you could point out what actually goes wrong it would be very helpful.

Comment: Dear. From your error, i can see that dylib missing in your project please add it from build phase tab. Let me know after this.

Comment: I've tried adding dylib but I still have same issue.